# Run PowerShell as elevated for another user

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a command as the Admin user with elevated permissions but PowerShell doesn't support this method.

```
Start-Process 
-FilePath "powershell" 
-ArgumentList "-Command New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $server -WebAccessServer $server -SessionHost $server" 
-Verb RunAs 
-Credential $creds

Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

The combination of `Verb` and `Credential` are not supported.

```
NAME
    Start-Process

SYNTAX
    Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError <string>]
    [-RedirectStandardInput <string>] [-RedirectStandardOutput <string>] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-Wait] [-UseNewEnvironment]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [-PassThru] [-Verb <string>] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-Wait]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

So how can I run an elevated powershell as another user??

UPDATE:
I've come up with this nasty solution but unfortunately it prompts me to approve Elevated permissions which of course is because of UAT.

```
Start-Process 
-Credential $creds 
-FilePath "powershell" 
-ArgumentList "Start-Process 
    -Verb RunAs 
    -FilePath powershell 
    -ArgumentList '-Command New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $server -WebAccessServer $server -SessionHost $server'"
```

Is there a way to run that above command as the Domain Admin for automated deployment??

Comment: It is usually considered unwise to have admin credentials (*especially* domain admin credentials) in a variable like that.  Can't you just log in with the right credentials to begin with?

Comment: Harry Johnston - I understand that but it I still need to run the command as that user which I still couldn't do.

Comment: That's by design.  A non-privileged user isn't supposed to be able to elevate to a privileged context without user interaction, though of course there are ways around it if you set them up in advance.  One option (not necessarily the best or simplest, just the only one I happen to know will work) would be to use `srvany` or preferably a similar third-party tool like `nssm` to create a system service ...

Comment: ... configure it to run in the domain admin account, and [change the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380009/886887) so that it can be started by unprivileged users, or by your particular user.  (The link shows code for changing the permissions, but you can just take the SDDL string and use it with the `sc sdset` command.)

Comment: Ok cool, Thanks Harry. Will look in to it.  Certainly can't find any other way!

Comment: The usual answer I give to this question: "You cannot automatically elevate from a non-admin account to an admin account without provoking the UAC prompt. This is by design." (If this was possible, it is exactly what all malware would do!)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Running Powershell without UAC Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581334/elevate-without-prompt-verb-runas-start-process)

Hope this helps.